# CSS - barra (decoração)

Tags: html, css

[image: ideia]

Estou a tentar criar uma barra como a que aparece na imagem, a barra que tem product etc.
Tenho o seguinte codigo:

```
 <div id="topcart"> 
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ISBN</th>
            <th>Book</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Subtotal</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>  
    </thead>
        </div>
```

e depois em CSS tenho o seguinte;

```
#topcart{
    overflow: hidden;
    display:block;
}
```

mas não esta a fazer nada. não é o overflow que faz com que a barra apareça como na imagem?

Comment: Overflow serve  para indicar ao navegador o que ele deve fazer com o conteúdo que não cabe dentro de uma camada, segundo as dimensões que lhe foram atribuídas. hidden: Este valor indica que os conteúdos que, pelo tamanho da camada, não caibam nela, se devem ocultar.

Comment: poderia dizer por gentileza qual é elemento em CSS que permita fazer a barra em azul? já procurei e não consegui encontrar.

Comment: <style>#topcart  { background-color: #0000FF }</style>

Comment: a cor da barra product é +- esta #71658B

Comment: eu nao quero a cor mas sim como fazer a barra!

Comment: o elemento em css que permite fazer a barra em azul é background-color.

Comment: pois entretanto ja percebi isso, o problema é que no meu codigo não esta funcionado. porque sera?

Comment: tem como falar no chat com voce?surgiu uma duvida?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57991/discussion-between-leo-caracciolo-and-diana-madeira).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> word-spacing é o espaço entre as palavras
>
> padding-left é espaço a esquerda

```css
#topcart  { 
font-family: Arial, courier, serif;
background-color: #71658B;
color: #FFFFFF;
word-spacing: 20px;
padding-left: 80px;
}
```

```html
 <div id="topcart"> 
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ISBN</th>
            <th>Book</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Subtotal</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>  
    </thead>
  </div>
```

Comment: editei a resposta que tinha um erro em tr